# How to send an image file from React.js to Spring Boot Rest API without using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, api, rest

## How to save an Image using Springboot rest api and React.js

I am trying to make a react application and also I have a Spring boot Rest API. I have created following code and it is working well with POSTMAN. My problem is, I don't know how to send the image file from react to my api. Plese provide me the full react code part. (I don't want use axios)

**This is my Springboot Rest API part (This is working without any problem)**

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<Object> fileUpload(@RequestParam("File") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
        
        File myfile = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY+file.getOriginalFilename());
        myfile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myfile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        FileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        fos.close();
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Success.."+FileName,HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
```

**This is my React part**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Postview from '../componant/postview';
import Navigation from '../componant/navigation';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import '../pages/profile.css';

export default function Profile() {

    var userId = sessionStorage.getItem("userID");
    const [imgOne, setImgOne] = useState()
    const [postBody, setPostBody] = useState()
    const [postTitle, setPostTitle] = useState()

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navigation /><br />
            <Row>
                <Col md="9">
                    <Postview />
                </Col>
                <Col md="3">
                    <Card >
                        <Card.Body >
                            <Form>
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                                    <Form.Label>Images</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="file" value={imgOne} onChange={(e) => setImgOne(e.target.value)} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                                    <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="email" value={postTitle} onChange={(e) => setPostTitle(e.target.value)} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                                    <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} value={postBody} onChange={(e) => setPostBody(e.target.value)} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Button id='postBtn' variant="primary">Post</Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Also I have call some api using following way and it is also worked. **I want a code for above problem just like below**

```
  const registerClick = (e) => {

        try {
            let result = fetch('http://localhost:8080/user-save', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "email": "" + email + "",
                    "name": "" + name + "",
                    "password": "" + password + "",
                })
            });
            navigate('/');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippets for `React` and `Sprint-Boot` should be enough to get you started.

##### Explaination:

I've created 3 state variables that simply look for form changes. Whenever the form gets dirty, the state variables capture the changes. The submit button calls the `handleForm(e)` handler that submits the data to your spring `@RestController` which runs on `localhost` with port `8080`

###### React implementation:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Form() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");

  function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", file);
    data.append("title", title);
    data.append("desc", desc);

    fetch("http://localhost:8080/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    });
  }

  function handleFileChange(e) {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          placeholder="title"
          onKeyUp={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="description"
          placeholder="description"
          onKeyUp={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="file" name="image" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => handleForm(e)}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

###### Spring-Boot implementation

```java
package com.springboot.learning.controllers;

import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    private static final String UPLOAD_PATH = "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/project-name/src/main/resources/static/images/";

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String desc) {

        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(desc);
        System.out.println(fileName);
        try {
            file.transferTo(new File(UPLOAD_PATH + fileName));
            return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }

    }

}
```

###### P.S: You may need to create the folder `resources/static/images` in your project if not already existing.